# about Artifactory license update

Tags: artifactory

Now, I am using Artifactory pro edition.
And It's license will expire soon later.

So, I want to update my License by JFrog site(https://jfrog.co.jp/buy-now/#pro).
But It's show dialog "OOPS... SOMETHING WENT WRONG invalid-key".

Can't I update my license until it expires?

Comment: I solved this issue, by email from jFrog support. Then sent other web form to me, and I can update license soon. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be legit and it can happen due to extra spaces or indentation issues. I would recommend to generate a new key and replace it.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by Lakshmi, this can happen if for some reason you added extra spaces or line breaks while copying the license key (this can happen when copy pasting from email for example). Make sure you enter the complete license key without any of these.
If it does not work you should contact service@jfrog.com